# How to remove any grid cells beyond where they intersect with a polygon in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, geometry, maps, ggspatial

I have created a grid based on a dataset of birds observed offshore and created a polygon of the coast using the `mapdata` package. I want to reduce the grid to only cells that occur over ocean or that intersect with the coast.

I can achieve the aesthetic of this by layering the polygon over the grid, but that doesn't show me how many grid cells meet my above criteria. I have tried to clip the grid with no success using `st_difference` as demonstrated by my below script and the attached plot.

I have used `dput` to provide you with the grid data but have also commented out the steps I took to create the grid in case that provides any insight into the problem.

```
# Load required libraries
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(maps)
library(mapdata)
library(ggpubr)
library(ggspatial)
library(sf)

# Where I create the grid based on my data. 
# I have pasted the product of this code above ... 
# but am providing it for context.

#data_sf = st_as_sf(bird_data, 
#                    coords = c("decimalLongitude", "decimalLatitude"),
#                    crs = 4326)
#bbox <- st_bbox(data_sf)
#tmp_grid <- st_make_grid(bbox, cellsize=5)
#grid <- st_as_sf(tmp_grid)
```

```
## I create the outline of the coastline using the following script.

#load world map data
world_map <- map_data("world2Hires")
# Extract Canada and USA polygons
country_polygons <- world_map[world_map$region %in% c('Canada', 'USA'), ]
country_polygons$long = (360 - country_polygons$long)*-1

#convert to sf object
land_sf <- st_as_sf(country_polygons, coords = c("long", "lat"), 
                    crs= 4326, remove = FALSE)
land_sf <- st_union(land_sf)

#clip grid and show where it does not overlap with land_sf
clipped_grid <- st_difference(grid,land_sf)

lons = c(-75, -50)     # (max longitude, min longitude)
lats = c(40, 55)       # (min latitude, max latitude)

#plot the grid and the land polygon
ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = clipped_grid, color = "red") +
  theme_classic() + 
  geom_sf(data = land_sf) +
  coord_sf(xlim = lons, ylim = lats)
```

[image]

#### Data:

```
#grid data
grid = structure(list(x = structure(list(structure(list(structure(c(-73.9167, 
-68.9167, -68.9167, -73.9167, -73.9167, 40.0167, 40.0167, 45.0167, 
45.0167, 40.0167), dim = c(5L, 2L))), class = c("XY", "POLYGON", 
"sfg")), structure(list(structure(c(-68.9167, -63.9167, -63.9167, 
-68.9167, -68.9167, 40.0167, 40.0167, 45.0167, 45.0167, 40.0167
), dim = c(5L, 2L))), class = c("XY", "POLYGON", "sfg")), structure(list(
    structure(c(-63.9167, -58.9167, -58.9167, -63.9167, -63.9167, 
    40.0167, 40.0167, 45.0167, 45.0167, 40.0167), dim = c(5L, 
    2L))), class = c("XY", "POLYGON", "sfg")), structure(list(
    structure(c(-58.9167, -53.9167, -53.9167, -58.9167, -58.9167, 
    40.0167, 40.0167, 45.0167, 45.0167, 40.0167), dim = c(5L, 
    2L))), class = c("XY", "POLYGON", "sfg")), structure(list(
    structure(c(-53.9167, -48.9167, -48.9167, -53.9167, -53.9167, 
    40.0167, 40.0167, 45.0167, 45.0167, 40.0167), dim = c(5L, 
    2L))), class = c("XY", "POLYGON", "sfg")), structure(list(
    structure(c(-73.9167, -68.9167, -68.9167, -73.9167, -73.9167, 
    45.0167, 45.0167, 50.0167, 50.0167, 45.0167), dim = c(5L, 
    2L))), class = c("XY", "POLYGON", "sfg")), structure(list(
    structure(c(-68.9167, -63.9167, -63.9167, -68.9167, -68.9167, 
    45.0167, 45.0167, 50.0167, 50.0167, 45.0167), dim = c(5L, 
    2L))), class = c("XY", "POLYGON", "sfg")), structure(list(
    structure(c(-63.9167, -58.9167, -58.9167, -63.9167, -63.9167, 
    45.0167, 45.0167, 50.0167, 50.0167, 45.0167), dim = c(5L, 
    2L))), class = c("XY", "POLYGON", "sfg")), structure(list(
    structure(c(-58.9167, -53.9167, -53.9167, -58.9167, -58.9167, 
    45.0167, 45.0167, 50.0167, 50.0167, 45.0167), dim = c(5L, 
    2L))), class = c("XY", "POLYGON", "sfg")), structure(list(
    structure(c(-53.9167, -48.9167, -48.9167, -53.9167, -53.9167, 
    45.0167, 45.0167, 50.0167, 50.0167, 45.0167), dim = c(5L, 
    2L))), class = c("XY", "POLYGON", "sfg")), structure(list(
    structure(c(-73.9167, -68.9167, -68.9167, -73.9167, -73.9167, 
    50.0167, 50.0167, 55.0167, 55.0167, 50.0167), dim = c(5L, 
    2L))), class = c("XY", "POLYGON", "sfg")), structure(list(
    structure(c(-68.9167, -63.9167, -63.9167, -68.9167, -68.9167, 
    50.0167, 50.0167, 55.0167, 55.0167, 50.0167), dim = c(5L, 
    2L))), class = c("XY", "POLYGON", "sfg")), structure(list(
    structure(c(-63.9167, -58.9167, -58.9167, -63.9167, -63.9167, 
    50.0167, 50.0167, 55.0167, 55.0167, 50.0167), dim = c(5L, 
    2L))), class = c("XY", "POLYGON", "sfg")), structure(list(
    structure(c(-58.9167, -53.9167, -53.9167, -58.9167, -58.9167, 
    50.0167, 50.0167, 55.0167, 55.0167, 50.0167), dim = c(5L, 
    2L))), class = c("XY", "POLYGON", "sfg")), structure(list(
    structure(c(-53.9167, -48.9167, -48.9167, -53.9167, -53.9167, 
    50.0167, 50.0167, 55.0167, 55.0167, 50.0167), dim = c(5L, 
    2L))), class = c("XY", "POLYGON", "sfg"))), class = c("sfc_POLYGON", 
"sfc"), precision = 0, bbox = structure(c(xmin = -73.9167, ymin = 40.0167, 
xmax = -48.9167, ymax = 55.0167), class = "bbox"), crs = structure(list(
    input = "EPSG:4326", wkt = "GEOGCRS[\"WGS 84\",\n    ENSEMBLE[\"World Geodetic System 1984 ensemble\",\n        MEMBER[\"World Geodetic System 1984 (Transit)\"],\n        MEMBER[\"World Geodetic System 1984 (G730)\"],\n        MEMBER[\"World Geodetic System 1984 (G873)\"],\n        MEMBER[\"World Geodetic System 1984 (G1150)\"],\n        MEMBER[\"World Geodetic System 1984 (G1674)\"],\n        MEMBER[\"World Geodetic System 1984 (G1762)\"],\n        MEMBER[\"World Geodetic System 1984 (G2139)\"],\n        ELLIPSOID[\"WGS 84\",6378137,298.257223563,\n            LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1]],\n        ENSEMBLEACCURACY[2.0]],\n    PRIMEM[\"Greenwich\",0,\n        ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433]],\n    CS[ellipsoidal,2],\n        AXIS[\"geodetic latitude (Lat)\",north,\n            ORDER[1],\n            ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433]],\n        AXIS[\"geodetic longitude (Lon)\",east,\n            ORDER[2],\n            ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433]],\n    USAGE[\n        SCOPE[\"Horizontal component of 3D system.\"],\n        AREA[\"World.\"],\n        BBOX[-90,-180,90,180]],\n    ID[\"EPSG\",4326]]"), class = "crs"), n_empty = 0L)), row.names = c(NA, 
15L), class = c("sf", "data.frame"), sf_column = "x", agr = structure(integer(0), class = "factor", levels = c("constant", 
"aggregate", "identity"), names = character(0)))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `sf::st_intersects` to get which polygons (i.e. `grid`) are intersecting with the points (i.e. `land_sf`), and then simply use `[` to filter out non-intersecting ones.

```r
clipped_grid <- grid[sf::st_intersects(grid, land_sf, sparse = FALSE),]  

ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = clipped_grid, color = "red") +
  theme_classic() + 
  geom_sf(data = land_sf) +
  coord_sf(xlim = lons, ylim = lats)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2024-02-21 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: While this is very useful, I'm hoping to keep the grid cells over the water (bottom and top right) and only crop the squares that are fully on land (top left). Any suggestions?

Comment: @maribio18 same principal applies. We need to do an *intersects*. But instead of just using the points (`land_sf`), you need to also use a polygon feature of water bodies. It'll probably would look like this: ```grid[sf::st_intersects(grid, land_sf, sparse = FALSE) | sf::st_intersects(grid, water_body_poly, sparse = FALSE),]```. By using `|` between the two *intersects*, we keep the grids that are either intersecting the shoreline or the water body polygon. Good luck :)